# Multiple open-close or single?

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have a dashboard on my site. On the main dashboard page I collect a lot of different metrics. Recently I have been seeing 504 errors on this page, and I think it is related to the database not performing properly.

Right now the user base is very small, just a handful of people using the site. At time, its buttery smooth, but again, recently 504s have been popping up.

I have maybe 20 different hits on two separate databases on this page. Is it better to open connection/do db A requests/close, and then open connection/do db B requests/ close,

Or just open/pull/close for each hit?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest implementing a singleton for each user to reuse the database connection if there are 20 different calls to the database. The singleton is per user request and not to be shared across all the requests to the application. Let's see what others have to offer.